# jquery issue with on and live

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
var $reviewButton = $('span.review_button');

$reviewButton
    .live('click',
        function(){

            $('#add_reviews').show(); 

        }
    )
```

Later in the script, I use an AJAX call to load some content and another instance of $('span.review_button') enters the picture. I updated my code above to use '.live' because the click event was not working with the AJAX generated review button.

This code works, as the .live(click //) event works on both the static 'span.review_button' and the AJAX generated 'span.review_button'

I see however that .live is depracated so I have tried to follow the jquery documentations instructions by switching to '.on' but when I switch to the code below, I have the same problem I had before switching to '.live' in which the click function works with the original instance of 'span.review_button' but not on the AJAX generated instance:

```
var $reviewButton = $('span.review_button');

$reviewButton
    .on('click',
        function(){

            $('#add_reviews').show(); 

        }
    )
```

Suggestions?

Comment: You can't just change `.live` to `.on`.  You need to change the syntax a bit.  Check the docs: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct syntax for event delegation is:

```
$("body").on("click", "span.review_button", function() {
    $("#add_reviews").show(); 
});
```

Here instead of `body` you may use any *static* parent element of `"span.review_button"`.

**Attention!** As discussed in the comments, you should use string value as a second argument of [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method in delegated events approach, but *not a jQuery object*.

Comment: not quite... would `$reviewButton` not be a reference to an empty jQuery object?

Comment: @VisioN: I'm assuming `span.review_button` elements don't exist when the page loads, which is why he was using `.live`.  So, when this is called, it'll be empty or just have the elements that existed then.  jQuery objects don't magically include elements added later.  Plus `.on` wants a selector, not a jQuery object.

Comment: because, as mentioned, the span doesn't exist in the document at the time `$reviewButton` is set

Comment: Agreed. We can't use jQuery object as a second argument here. Very great catch. Thanks, ahren and RocketHazmat.

Comment: Sounds right.. since it would just be using the cached elements that exist at the time of dom ready

Comment: no...one instance of span.review_button certainly does exist when $reviewButton is set. A second instance comes along later with AJAX

Comment: @absentx - the one that gets added later via AJAX would not be a part of `$reviewButton` - as that would only contain references to elements that exist at the point you set it.

Comment: Right...makes complete sense. Selection and the dom getting clearer every day!

Answer (score 6):

This is because you need to use the delegation version of `on()`.

```
$("#parentElement").on('click', '.child', function(){});
```

`#parentElement` must exist in the DOM at the time you bind the event.

The event will bubble up the DOM tree, and once it reaches `#parentElement`, it is checked for it's origin, and if it matches `.child`, executes the function.
So, with this in mind, it's best to bind the event to the *closest parent element existing in the DOM at time of binding* - for best performance.

Answer (score 3):

Set your first selector (in this case, div.content) as the parent container that contains the clicked buttons as well as any DOM that will come in using AJAX. If you have to change the entire page for some reason, it can even be change to "body", but you want to try and make the selector as efficient as possible, so narrow it down to the closest parent DOM element that won't change.

Secondly, you want to apply the click action to span.review_button, so that is reflected in the code below.

```
// $('div.content') is the content area to watch for changes
// 'click' is the action applied to any found elements
// 'span.review_button' the element to apply the selected action 'click' to. jQuery is expecting this to be a string.
$('div.content').on('click', 'span.review_button', function(){
    $('#add_reviews').show(); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks :) Updated to reflect.